# Managing Permissions for Multiple Team Types (Company Teams and Project Teams) with Spatie Roles and Permissions in Laravel

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

I'm working on a Laravel application where I need to manage permissions for two types of teams: company teams and project teams. I'm using the Spatie Roles and Permissions package, but I've encountered a limitation because the package supports only a single team_foreign_key.

Company Teams:

Each company can have multiple teams, and I need to manage permissions for these company teams.
The team_foreign_key for company teams is company_id.
Project Teams:

In addition to company teams, I also have project teams, each associated with a specific project.
The team_foreign_key for project teams is project_id.
My goal is to manage roles and permissions separately for these two types of teams while using the same Spatie Roles and Permissions package. However, the package's default behavior supports only one team_foreign_key at a time.

I'm looking for guidance on how to customize the Spatie Roles and Permissions package or implement a solution that allows me to manage permissions for both types of teams efficiently. If you have any code examples, best practices, or resources related to this specific use case, please share them.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the TEAMS features you must update your config/permission.php config file:

must set 'teams' => true

```
'teams' => true
```